# JQuery - How do I get this function to run once when clicking twice

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get this function to run once when I click twice on the button element two times (not double clikcing, just clicking twice on it at any point in time) that initializes it and then make it reset.

```
<a href="#" onclick="popHover()">

$('.challenge_popover').popover()

var clicked = false

function popHover() {

        // I NEED THIS PART TO RUN ON THE FIRST CLICK
        if (clicked == false)
        {
        $('.challenge_popover').popover('destroy')
        }

         // AND THIS PART TO RUN ON THE SECOND CLICK
        $(document).live('mousedown', function(e) { 

            if (e.which == 1)  

            {
            $('.challenge_popover').popover()
            clicked = true
            }

        });

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by click twice? Double click or two clicks? Also, you're registering the mousedown event handler each time you call popover().

Comment: Two clicks. Clicking the element at any point in time.

Comment: Still ambiguous. Do you mean `.one()` to make something happen only the first time or `on('dblclick')` which should explain itself?

Comment: Yeah, not the fast double clicking. Just one, then at any point in time clicking on it again.

Comment: You have answers so I'm not going to post one but please don't use `var clicked = false;` - what if a second thing uses that too?

Comment: @popnoodles probably it needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function so that scope of the variable is contained

Comment: Or the anchor/button could have data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use inline event handling like that; just leave the anchor bare:

```
<a href="#">
```

Then, attach the click handler with jQuery:

```
$('.challenge_popover')
    .popover()
    .on('click', popHover)
```

Next up, your click event handler:

```
function popHover()
{
    // we keep the clicked state on the element itself
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');

    if (!clicked) {
        // action #1
        $(this).popover('destroy')
    } else {
         // AND THIS PART TO RUN ON THE SECOND CLICK
         $(this).popover();
    }
    // toggle clicked state
    $(this).data('clicked', !clicked);
}
```

I wasn't sure what happens on the third click; I assume it should do action #1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery `.dblclick()` that will help a lot.

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "dblclick" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
$('.challenge_popover').popover();

var clicked = false;

function popHover() {
        if (clicked) {
            $('.challenge_popover').popover('destroy')
        } else {
            $('.challenge_popover').popover()
        }

        clicked = !clicked;
}
```

Comment: Didn't try this, but I think it wouldve worked. It's just that Jack's method made it better than I had envisioned it working in the first place.